# bloco de código só funciona com F5

Tags: jquery

alguém saberia me dizer porque esse bloco de código só funciona após atualizar a página?

```
var count = 0;

$( document ).ready(function() {

//  alert("testando bloco");
  $("#select_n").attr('id', 'select_' + count);

  $("#add").click(function(){
    count ++;

    // desnecessario
    $("#select_n").attr('id', 'select_' + count);

    //$("#filtro_subdisciplinas_select").attr('id', 'subdisciplinas_select_' + count);
    $("#subdisciplina_select_n").attr('id', 'subdisciplina_select_' + count);
    //$("#carro_div_n").attr('id', 'carro_div_' + carro_temp);

  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Voce ta referindo `$("#select_n")` e trocando seu id pra `select_' + count`. Então dentro do `click` tenta referir o id novo. `$("#select_"+(count-1))`.

```
var count = 0;

$( document ).ready(function() {
   //  alert("testando bloco");
   $("#select_n").attr('id', 'select_' + count);

   $("#add").click(function(){
        count ++;

        // desnecessario
        $("#select_"+(count-1)).attr('id', 'select_' + count);

        //$("#filtro_subdisciplinas_select").attr('id', 'subdisciplinas_select_' + count);
        $("#subdisciplina_select_"+(count-1)).attr('id', 'subdisciplina_select_' + count);
        //$("#carro_div_n").attr('id', 'carro_div_' + carro_temp);
    });
 });
```

Comment: é que o botao #add gera outro campo com id $("#select_n"), nao aparece ai porque ele faz isso por meio de um framework chamado de gem em ruby on rails

Comment: Tenta mostrar mais informação na sua pergunta @ErasmoSantos. Nao uso ruby on rails mais alem do que falei nao vejo erro neste pedaço de código.